# Animating values from and object using getters and setters with gsap and svg.js

Tags: gsap, svg.js

Im attempting to animate gradient stops within an svg.js class using GSAP. To do so am trying to animate values inside an object which are passed to the svg gradient function. Code below. At the moment not allot happens and I was hopping for the gradient to animate from left to right. [Here is the codepen](https://codepen.io/limitedunlimited/pen/gOLLezz?editors=0010)

```
var gradientStops = {
  _start: 0,
  get start() {
    return this._start;
  },
  set start(value) {
    this._start = value;
  },
  _end: 1,
  get end() {
    return this._end;
  },
  set end(value) {
    this._end = value;
  }
};

var draw = new SVG().addTo("#svg").attr({
  viewBox: "0 0 100 100",
  class: "w-2/3 bg-red-50"
});
var gradient = draw.gradient("linear", function (add) {
  add.stop(gradientStops.start, "hsla(352, 99%, 90%, 1.00)");
  add.stop(gradientStops.end, "hsla(352, 99%, 50%, 1.00)");
});

var globe = draw.circle(50).fill(gradient).cx(50).cy(50);

gsap.to(gradientStops, {
  start: 1,
  end: 0,
  duration: 2,
  yoyo: true,
  repeat: -1
});
Th
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: For reference, this [was answered on the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/27154-change-svg-gradient-with-object-getters-and-setters/) but the OP wants an SVG.js only way of animating the gradient.

Comment: Then op should rewrite the question!